# Having trouble with decimal float in struct array

Tags: c++, floating-point, dynamic-arrays

I am having some trouble and I cant really even figure out what is wrong, so I needed some help.
I need to take a percentage of a number that one of the structs in my array has, for each one.

my struct looks like

```
struct person{
    int number;
    string name;
    float share;
}
```

So I use a for loop to get the total of number, no problem, all comes out good. But when I try to get what percent of the total I always get a zero.

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfPersons;i++){
    people[i].share = 100 * ((people[i].number)/totalNumber);
}
```

I don't understand what is going wrong here but people[i].share always comes out as 0.00 when I cout it.

literally all I do after this is cout it and I get the correct values from number and totalNumber. So I'm like really confused.

If I flip the division problem around I get answers(not the right ones obviously), so I know that there is data in the fields when the for loop runs. But where is it going when I run the equation the way I need to run it?

I tried initializing it and leaving uninitialized, swapping the pointers for ints made inside the loop, and more and I always get the same result.

Please help me understand.

Comment: What is the type of `totalNumer`?

Comment: it is an int, should that be a float too?

Comment: If both operands of the division are integers then the result is also an integer, so 5/10 == 0. Cast one side to float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your type of `totalnumber` is `int` and `person.number` is int as well.

For operation between `int`s, the return value is still `int`

Expanding `people[i].share = 100 * ((people[i].number)/totalNumber);`

It would be something like `people[i].share = 100 * ( 1/10 );`

=> `people[i].share = 100 * ( 0 );`

=> `people[i].share = 0;`

So you will get 0 as a result;

To prevent it, cast one of int to float.

`people[i].share = 100 * ((static_cast<float>(people[i].number))/totalNumber);`